# Are table headings functional?

Tags: matrix, formatting, list-manipulation

Are table headings for aesthetics only?

For example, if I have:

```
table1 = TableForm[{{1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
                    {0, 0, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 0, 0},
                    {0, 1, 1, 0, 0}}, 
                   TableHeadings -> {{"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"},
                                     {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"}}]
```

is there any way to refer to a part of the table by the heading names?

For example, if I want the position of all 1's in the table,

```
Position[table1, 1]
```

I would like this to return both numbers and letters. Is this possible?

Comment: What wasn't really spelled out by the answers, but is important to understand, is that the purpose of `TableForm` is displaying tables in a pretty way.  Don't use `TableForm` as a data structure (unless you know for certain that this is an advantage for you...).  Just use it to display a table stored as a `List` in two-dimensional (readable) form.

Answer (score 6):

Let's figure it out by inspecting the full form of a `TableForm`:

```
TableForm[{{1, 2}, {3, 1}}, TableHeadings -> {{"a", "b"}, {"c", "d"}}] // FullForm
```

> TableForm[List[List[1,2],List[3,1]],Rule[TableHeadings,List[List["a","b"],List["c","d"]]]]

Evidently, then, we can obtain the list as the first element of the `TableForm` and we can find the headings, assuming they exist, from the `TableHeadings` rule.  Under these assumptions, one solution is to create a parallel table of the desired addresses of all list positions and index into that:

```
addresses = Outer[List, Sequence @@ (TableHeadings /. Cases[table1, _Rule]), 1];
addresses[[Sequence @@ #]] & /@ Position[table1 // First, 1]
```

> {{1,a},{1,b},{2,b},{3,c},{4,c},{4,d},{4,e},{5,c},{5,e},{6,a},{6,b},{7,b},{7,c}}

Comment: Thank you @whuber! I am still very new at this and I didn't know one could use //Fullform inspect functions.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative formulation that does the same thing as the answer by @whuber but uses what I think is more idiomatic syntax:

```
Flatten[Pick[
  Outer[List, Sequence @@ OptionValue[Options[table1], TableHeadings]
   ],
  table1[[1]],
  1],
 1]

{{"1", "a"}, {"1", "b"}, {"2", "b"}, {"3", "c"}, {"4", "c"}, {"4", 
  "d"}, {"4", "e"}, {"5", "c"}, {"5", "e"}, {"6", "a"}, {"6", 
  "b"}, {"7", "b"}, {"7", "c"}}
```

The table headings are options, so they (like all options) can be extracted using `OptionValue[Options[table1], TableHeadings]`. I then construct a matrix of tuples with the combined table headings, similar to what @whuber did (using `Outer`). The command [`Pick`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Pick.html) does the remaining work.

Comment: I had never seen these functions either. I will read up on Options too. Thanks @Jens, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

To emphasize Szabolcs' point, if you had data you wanted to display and work with, you might put and row and column identifiers in separate lists

```
rowNames = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"};
columnNames = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"};
data = {{1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1,1, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 0}};
```

and use TableForm[ ] to display it in a table:

```
TableForm[data, TableHeadings -> {rowNames, columnNames}]
```

But, to get an element from data, you would probably use some function like this:

```
getdata[row_, col_] := Module[{r, c}, 
 r = Position[rowNames, row][[1, 1]]; 
 c = Position[columnNames, col][[1, 1]]; 
 data[[r, c]]
]
```

in the following manner:

```
getdata["2", "b"]
```

to get the returned value of 1. So, the table display created by TableForm[ ] is just for *display* and not a normal way to store data.

Answer (score 0):

```
data = {{1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 
    1}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 0}};

rowHdrs = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"};

colHdrs = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"};
```

Using version 10 capabilities of  [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html) and [`Dataset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dataset.html)

```
$Version

(* "10.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (July 7, 2015)" *)

dataset = Dataset[<|Thread[rowHdrs -> (<|Thread[colHdrs -> #]|> & /@ data)]|>]
```

[image]

```
keys = Position[dataset, 1] /. Key[x_] :> x

(* {{"1", "a"}, {"1", "b"}, {"2", "b"}, {"3", "c"}, {"4", "c"}, {"4", "d"}, {"4",
   "e"}, {"5", "c"}, {"5", "e"}, {"6", "a"}, {"6", "b"}, {"7", "b"}, {"7", 
  "c"}} *)
```

Verifying that all the values are one

```
dataset @@@ keys

(* {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1} *)
```